# Is it safe to lift after a bout of insomnia?

Tags: stronglifts, sleep, safety

Basically went to bed at midnight and didn't fall asleep until almost 4, so I got maybe 3 hours of sleep last night. To make matters worse I skipped my workout (Stronglifts 5x5) yesterday because M/W/F fit better into my schedule this week so now I really feel like I shouldn't skip today.

So I just want to make sure I'm not putting myself at risk of injury because I'm overtired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting yourself at a *higher* risk. There's always the chance for injury to happen whether you slept for 12 hours or none.

What most likely will happen is that you'll feel tired sooner and won't be able to lift as much as you usually do.

Comment: Well, I did it. Only one I couldn't finish my sets on was overhead press, but I always have trouble with that one. I could feel my form being poor on the squats though, it's probably good I'm only up to 120lbs!

Answer (score 2):

A regular training program will eventually encounter head colds, bad sleep, and other curve balls of life.

Do your warmups and make sure you have the mental wherewithal to handle your coordination and strength. Worst case scenario, get in there and do ~75% of your weight or something of the sort. Unless you have a real injury I'd just throttle back the weight but make sure you still lift.

I've had some terrific days where I felt terrible, and some terrible days when I felt great. Sleep affects me (and probably you) more on the recovery side.